# Most of my symbolic x coords not showing up

Tags: tables, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

This one I haven't figured out yet.

This is a very basic bar graph, where I have `symbolic x coords` as the year number I am trying to display. However only the first year is displayed, and it is way off the column it is supposed to represent. I have tried having `xtick=data,` and `xtick={2001,2002,...,2016},`, I have tried `xticklabel` instead of `xtick`.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
%\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
%\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Myndir/} }
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      width=.9\linewidth,
    height=8cm,
    enlarge x limits = 0.33,
    ybar=2pt,
    bar width=4pt,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    xlabel={Ár},
    ylabel={Árleg uppsett vindorkugeta á heimsvísu (GW)},
    symbolic x coords={2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016},
    xtick=data,
%     xticklabels={2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016},
    legend columns=-1, % to set one line legend
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.35)},anchor=center},
%     legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2pt}},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}
      ]
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2001,6.5) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2002,7.3)};
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2003,8.1) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2004,8.2) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2005,11.5) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2006,14.7) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2007,20.3) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2008,26.9) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2009,38.5) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2010,39.1) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2011,40.6) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2012,45.0) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2013,36.0) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2014,51.7) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2015,63.6) };
      \addplot+[ybar, red] coordinates { (2016,54.6) };
      \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Árleg uppsett vindorkugeta á heimsvísu \protect\autocite{Alkhalidi} \label{fig:uppbygging}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I know I will need to reduce the size of the font of the symbolic x for this graph. But I find it weird I only get one year.
I would even be happy with periodic labels.

Here is how it looks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tikz program that shows how I think you would want your picture. I am not knowlegeable enough to point to the errors in your program, rather I have found a reasonable example in the pgfplots manual:
https://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/example_78.tex

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    width=120mm,
    height=8cm,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    xmin=2000.20,xmax=2016.4,
    xtick={2001,2002,...,2016},
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,rotate=45,anchor=east},
    ybar=2pt,
    bar width=4pt,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    xlabel={Ár},
    ylabel={Árleg uppsett vindorkugeta á heimsvísu (GW)},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\tiny}
   ]
    \addplot[red,fill] coordinates { (2001,6.5)(2002,7.3)
      (2003,8.1)(2004,8.2) (2005,11.5)(2006,14.7)
      (2007,20.3) (2008,26.9) (2009,38.5) (2010,39.1)
      (2011,40.6) (2012,45.0) (2013,36.0) (2014,51.7)
      (2015,63.6) (2016,54.6) };
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This did  the trick for me. Thank you for this.